# TFS Build, missing ref in compiler CLI: Error BC30002: Type 'xxx' is not defined

Tags: .net, tfs, build, reference, msbuild

I can't get a TFS Build to work on the server. I have A.exe referencing 2 class libraries:

-> A.EXE
     B.DLL
     C.DLL

I have Test class library with a reference to the EXE and the 2 class libraries:

-> Test.DLL
    A.EXE
    B.DLL
    C.DLL

I've identified the **EXE reference** passed to the compiler (VBC.exe in this case) **is missing when compiling the Test project**.

From a command line, running: `msbuild "theSolution.sln"`:

> vbc.exe /noconfig
>   /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic,System.Data,System.Diagnostics,System.Linq,System.Xml.Linq
>   /optioncompare:Binary /optionexplicit+  /optionstrict+ /optioninfer+
>   /nostdlib /platform:x86 /rootnamespace:SEAchange.Test
>   /sdkpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5" /highentropyva+
>   /doc:obj\Debug\doco.Test.xml
>   /define:"CONFIG=\"Debug\",DEBUG=-1,TRACE=-1,_MyType=\"Windows\",PLATFORM=\"AnyCPU\""

On Build server & Dev PC it includes the EXE reference and works:

> /reference:c:\TFSBuildAgents_work\1\s\packages\NUnit.3.9.0\lib\net45\nunit.framework.dll,**c:\TFSBuildAgents_work\1\s\A\bin\Debug\A.EXE**,c:\TFSBuildAgents_work\1\s\B\bin\Debug\B.dll,c:\TFSBuildAgents_work\1\s\C\bin\Debug\C.dll

On my build server, running via the build agent, it does NOT include the EXE reference and fails with Error BC30002: Type 'xxx' is not defined:

> /reference:c:\TFSBuildAgents_work\1\s\packages\NUnit.3.9.0\lib\net45\nunit.framework.dll,c:\TFSBuildAgents_work\1\s\B\bin\Debug\B.dll,c:\TFSBuildAgents_work\1\s\C\bin\Debug\C.dll,

Does anyone know how I can include the reference to the EXE on the build server?

This is the TFS MSBuild command:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe"
>   "c:\TFSBuildAgents_work\1\s\theSolution.sln" /nologo /nr:false
>   /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\TFSBuildAgents_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=cd19916c-1cb1-41e0-aa14-c251a8dd5925|SolutionDir=c:\TFSBuildAgents_work\1\s"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\TFSBuildAgents_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
>   /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release"
>   /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0"
>   /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_b2b3a2c7-b2fe-484a-80d8-1f427d4273ec_build_1_27"

<sub>Server: Win2016, On-Prem TFS2017sp2, VS2017

Dev: Win7, VS2017</sub>

Edit: Another project has been added and it references the EXE. Because it is built before the Test Project it fails, but with a different error message:

Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'A.EXE project' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project was upgraded from VS2010 to 2017 and from Jenkins to TFS.

I eventually just created a new solution and added all the projects. One had an incorrect reference path and caused the symptoms reported above.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer.